# Background animation looping smoothly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add a background animation that will move from right to left and will loop cleanly. So far the animation works from right to left using keyframes but after 30s it stops and starts all over again. It doesn’t look very clean and smooth. Is there any alternative solution for this?

```
body:before {
 content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-image: url("/media/background.svg");
  background-position: 0px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: cover;
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 30s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% { background-position: 0 0; }
  100% { background-position: -4000px 0; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `50%` keyframe to be the `100%` keyframe, and set the end background position to `-100vw`.

```css
body:before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/1200/1200");
  background-position: 0px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: cover;
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -100vw 0;
  }
}
```

And the same idea with `animation-timing-function: linear`:

```css
body:before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/1200/1200");
  background-position: 0px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: cover;
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -100vw 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help but this is not exactly what I am looking for. I just want it to go in the same direction smoothly so it starts and stops at the same point and looks like it is an infinite loop

Comment: If you add `animation-timing-function: linear;` then the animation will have the same speed during the entire animation and make it transition more smoothly.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier - added an example with linear.